# why my exception is not caught?

Tags: java

I have a code which generates the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at edu.createArrays(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:2188)
    at edu.considerCreatingArrays(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:2158)
    at edu.ExhaustivePCFGParser.parse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:339)
    at edu.LexicalizedParserQuery.parse(LexicalizedParserQuery.java:247)
    at edu.LexicalizedParser.apply(LexicalizedParser.java:283)
    at current.Gen.textParsen(Gen.java:162)
    at current.Gen.gen(Gen.java:90)
    at current.Foo.main(Foo.java:120)
```

I tried to catch it with the following code:

```
try {
    // this is the line which cause the exception
    LinkedList<Foo> erg = Gen.gen(rev);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("exception: out of memory");
}
```

but when I run the code the exception is not caught. How to solve this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888602/why-is-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-not-caught

Comment: PS: You should just print the stack trace (`e.printStackTrace()`), or if you're against that, use `System.err.println(e)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because that's not an `Exception` but an `Error`.

You could catch it as a `Throwable`

```
} catch (Throwable e) {
```

or specifically as `Error`

```
} catch (Error e) {
```

But there's not a lot you can do with such an error, apart trying to close the application in the cleanest way you can.

From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) :

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems
>   that a reasonable application should not try to catch

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_hierarchy.shtml