# Java - Catching System.load() Errors

Tags: java, load, java-native-interface

My main():

```
System.out.println("Start loading libraries");
boolean b2 = false;
try{
  b2 = FileManager.loadBinaries();
} catch (Exception e){
  System.out.println("Exception on loading");
}
System.out.println("Libraries loading ended");
```

LoadBinaries():

```
public static boolean loadBinaries(){
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    ArrayList<String> bins = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(os.indexOf("windows 7") >= 0 || os.indexOf("windows vista") >= 0){
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libcurld.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libfftw3f-3.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libmad.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libsamplerate.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/seven/mylib.dll");
    }
    else if(os.indexOf("windows xp") >= 0){
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libcurld.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libfftw3f-3.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libmad.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/libsamplerate.dll");
        bins.add("/nm/metadata/bin/win/xp/mylib.dll");
    } else if(os.indexOf("mac") >= 0){
        return false;
    }

    File f = null;
    for(String bin : bins){
        InputStream in = FileManager.class.getResourceAsStream(bin);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read = -1;
        try {
            String[] temp = bin.split("/");
            f = new File(LIB_FOLDER + "/" + temp[temp.length-1]);
            File realF = new File(f.getAbsolutePath());

            if(!realF.exists()){
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(realF);

                while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                fos.close();
                in.close();
            }
            System.out.println("Hello Load");
            System.load(f.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("Bye Load");
        } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Bye Exception"); FileManager.log(e.getMessage(), true); librariesLoaded = false; return false; }
    }

    System.out.println("Bye Method");
    librariesLoaded = true;
    return true;
}
```

When I run this main I get next output:

```
Start loading libraries
Hello Load
Bye Load
Hello Load
Bye Load
Hello Load
Bye Load
Hello Load
Bye Load
Hello Load
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\java\workspace\Lib\mylib.dll: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more detail
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at nm.player.FileManager.loadBinaries(FileManager.java:264)
    at nm.player.Player.<init>(Player.java:88)
    at nm.player.Player.main(Player.java:523)
```

This error is beacause it is missing some c++ system dlls. But my problem is not this. I am concern about where the program goes after this error! I don't see the print on the catch, the print after the loop in the method and neither the prints on the main, after loadbinaries is executed.

How can I catch this type of errors and deal with them? Example: When this error occur, I want to print "please intall c++ libraries" and control the flow after it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try replacing

```
catch (Exception e)
```

at the bottom of your `loadBinaries()` method with

```
catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
```

`UnsatisfiedLinkError` is a subclass of `Error`, which is *not* a subclass of `Exception`:  `Error` and `Exception` are both subclasses of `Throwable`, the root of the Java exception hierarchy.

Normally, you don't catch `Error`s.  However, it seems you have a reasonable case for doing so here, in that you can display a message to your users saying 'Library X is missing, please install it'.

Answer (score 6):

You're getting an [`UnsatisfiedLinkError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html) which is *not* a subclass of [`Exception`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and thus is not caught by your `catch` clause. If you want it to be caught change the catch to `catch(Error e)`.

You see, Java's exception hierarchy is a bit unintuitive. You have two classes, [`Exception`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and [`Error`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html), each of which extends [`Throwable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html). Thus, if you want to catch absolutely everything you need to catch Throwable (not recommended).

[`RuntimException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), by the way, is a subclass of [`Exception`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html).

Answer (score 1):

Its an error. and its good practice to not to catch the errors as per java PMD.

you can follow these link for more info

[When to catch java.lang.Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352780/when-to-catch-java-lang-error)

http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/strictexception.html

Comment: While it's a good general rule not to catch `Error` or its subclasses, this case seems to be an exception.