# Java try catch loop not catching after 1 loop

Tags: java, try-catch, vlcj

After one loop the program throws an exception at the new component line and quits. How do I loop until the user selects a file that works?

```
    while(!next){
            NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), folderChooser());
            try{
                EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent a = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
                a.release();
                next = true;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                next = false;
            }
    }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlcFactory.create(LibVlcFactory.java:158)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory.<init>(MediaPlayerFactory.java:236)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.onGetMediaPlayerFactory(EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.java:278)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.<init>(EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.java:168)
    at sv1.MainRun.try1(MainRun.java:107)
    at sv1.MainRun.<init>(MainRun.java:82)
    at sv1.Start.main(Start.java:7)
```

Comment: You don't have the `LibVlc` bindings on your classpath.

Comment: put continue; in the catch block if you want to ignore the error and loop.... not sure why,

Comment: What does that mean? How do I get them there. I know that when the user selects the correct file for VLCJ the program works.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` is a subclass of `Error`, not `Exception`.  Therefore, `catch(Exception e)` won't catch it.  However, I won't recommend that you change the `catch`, because this kind of error needs to be addressed somehow.  However, I don't know anything about `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent`.  (chrylis probably has the answer.)

Comment: @markg continue does not work

Comment: @ajb how do handle an error? I know that it is a problem (why I am aksing the user to repeat their action.

Comment: @Reid If you go back and try again, you'll just get the same error over again.  Somebody has to fix something first and then rerun the program.

Comment: that is where the folderchooser function comes in handy. It lets the user choose the function.

Comment: @Reid check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352780/when-to-catch-java-lang-error.  However, I think this probably one of those cases that falls into the "generally, never" category.

Comment: @Reid OK, after looking at the answer and your comments, I guess this might be a case where catching this one specific error may make sense.  Like I said, I don't know anything about the classes you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NoClassDefFoundError ncdx2 = null;
try  {

   ...

}  catch(NoClassDefFoundError ncdx)  {
   ncdx2 = ncdx;
}
if(ncdx != null)  {
   System.out.println("Try again: " + ncdx.getMessage());
}  else  {
   next = true;
}
```

This works, but it is definitely not recommended to use a *the absence of an error* as the terminating condition for a loop. Is there *any* way to check this without *having* to crash? Hopefully the API you are using has some information about some `isOkeyDokey()` function or something. If not, you could probably do some reflection. Anything is better than using an error as a replacement for logic.

More information: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+catch+an+error+in+java

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Where does ncdx2 come from?

Comment: It works great. I meant there is no isOkeyDokey() function. Thanks!!! (and my program is a hack job anyways, so a little more hacking is just par for the course)

Comment: Really! I honestly thought I was going to need to delete the answer. Glad to help. I just taught myself something!

Comment: `catch(Someclass x)` will catch any `Throwable` that is an instance of `Someclass` or a subclass of it; this is true regardless of whether `Someclass` is an `Exception` or an `Error`.

Answer (score 0):

see following modification

```
try
{
while(!next)
{
   NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), folderChooser());

   EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent a = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
   a.release();
   next = true;
}
}
catch(Exception e){
next = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would try move the try line

```
while(!next){
try{
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), folderChooser());

            EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent a = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
            a.release();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
}
```