# How do you replace actorFor?

Tags: scala, akka

Update: Source code for this question can be found [here](https://github.com/danluu/akka-concurrency-wyatt/blob/master/src/main/scala/Plane.scala). Courtesy of danluu.

Is there a standard way of replacing `actorFor` now that it has been deprecated?
Everything I found involves `actorSelection` - but getting 3  dependencies with setup with a selection is a real pita. Most of the discussion online just says not to use `actorFor`, but all the books on akka still make use of it (since they target pre-2.2 akka).

For example, let's say I have two actors `Pilot` and `Copilot`, both children of the `Plane` actor. Here is how they currently get a reference to each other (Akka Concurrency, Derek Wyatt, 2013):

```
// Plane.scala
...
override def preStart(){
    // Get our children going.

    //... create pilot/copilot (in a separate function)
    startPeople()

    // Tell them system is ready to go
    context.actorFor("Pilots/" + pilotName) ! ReadyToGo
    context.actorFor("Pilots/" + copilotName) ! ReadyToGo

// Pilot.scala
def receive = {
    case ReadyToGo =>
      val copilotName = context.system.settings.config.getString("zzz.akka.avionics.flightcrew.copilotName")
      copilot = context.actorFor("../" + copilotName)

// Copilot.scala
def receive = {
    case ReadyToGo =>
      pilot = context.actorFor("../" + pilotName)
      // watch out for pilot dying - take over control when he does
      context.watch(pilot)

    case Controls(ctr) =>
      controls = ctr

    case Terminated(_) =>
      // Pilot died!
      plane ! GiveMeControl
```

How would I do this without actorFor? Oh, and DI contructor injection would not work here - since both pilot and copilot need to know about each other.

Thanks.

P.S.: Here is the content of `startPeople()` method, not sure if it matters:

```
 def startPeople() {
    val plane = self

    val controls: ActorRef = actorForControls("ControlSurfaces")
    val autopilot: ActorRef = actorForControls("Autopilot")
    val altimeter: ActorRef = actorForControls("Altimeter")

    val people = context.actorOf(Props(new IsolatedStopSupervisor with OneForOneStrategyFactory
    {
      override def childStarter() {
        // These children get implicitly added to the hierarchy
        context.actorOf(Props(newCopilot(plane, autopilot, altimeter)), copilotName)
        context.actorOf(Props(newPilot(plane, autopilot, controls, altimeter)),  pilotName)
      }
    }), "Pilots")

    // Use the default strategy here, which restarts indefinitely
    context.actorOf(Props(newLeadFlightAttendant), attendantName)
    Await.result(people ? WaitForStart, 1.second)
  }
```

### Update: Solved

Thanks to Derek Wyatt (author) for the great answer.
As an example, here is how I used Futures with `map` notation, in one`Copilot` actor to acquire a dependency on `Pilot` actor:

```
package zzz.akka.avionics

import akka.actor._
import zzz.akka.avionics.Pilots.ReadyToGo
import zzz.akka.avionics.Plane.GiveMeControl
import akka.actor.Terminated
import zzz.akka.avionics.Plane.Controls
import scala.concurrent.Future
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.pattern.pipe

/** Copilot is a fail-over for the pilot.
 * Created by Andriy Drozdyuk on 05-Apr-14.
 */
class Copilot(plane: ActorRef, autopilot: ActorRef, altimeter: ActorRef) extends Actor with Stash {
  // Implicit execution context for futures
  implicit val ec = context.dispatcher
  // Implicit timeout for getting dependencies
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(1.second)

  val conf = context.system.settings.config
  var pilotName = conf.getString("zzz.akka.avionics.flightCrew.pilotName")

  var controls: ActorRef = context.system.deadLetters

  // Helps us get pilot dependency
  trait PilotAcquisition
  case class PilotAcquired(pilot: ActorRef) extends PilotAcquisition
  case class PilotNotAcquired(t: Throwable) extends PilotAcquisition

  // Acquire the pilot
  // Send either PilotAcquired or PilotNotAcquired message to self
  acquirePilot pipeTo self

  def acquirePilot: Future[PilotAcquisition] = {
    context.actorSelection("../" + pilotName).resolveOne() map {
      pilot => PilotAcquired(pilot)
    } recover {
      case t:Throwable => PilotNotAcquired(t)
    }
  }
  def receive: Receive = waitingForDependencies

  def waitingForDependencies: Receive = {
    case PilotAcquired(pilot) =>
      // Get all the messages we stashed and receive them
      unstashAll()
      // pass all our acquired dependencies in
      context.become(operational(pilot))

    case PilotNotAcquired(t) => throw new IllegalStateException(s"Failed to instantiate: $t")

    // Any other message save for later
    case _ => stash()
  }

  // All our dependencies have been acquired
  def operational(pilot: ActorRef) : Receive = {
    case ReadyToGo =>
      // Start watch on the pilot in case he kicks it
      context.watch(pilot)

    case Controls(ctr) =>
      controls = ctr

    case Terminated(_) =>
      // Pilot died!
      plane ! GiveMeControl

  }


}
```

Comment: its a nitpik but I wouldn't recommend catching Throwables. You wouldn't want to catch an Error and convert it to something that the JVM can't see to manage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352780/when-to-catch-java-lang-error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ActorSelection` is really the way to replace `actorFor`.  However, as I've already stated in the book, using Actor paths or selections can make your app quite brittle.

```
context.actorSelection("../someactor") ! ReadyToGo
context.actorSelection(self / "someChild" / "someGrandchild") ! ReadyToGo
```

Change your actor hierarchy, and your app starts failing.  However, at least with `ActorSelection` you get some timeout errors instead of just getting things sent to the dead letter office.

Now, if you want to start grabbing references, that's a different story and I suggest doing it with `Future`s.

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.pattern.pipe

class MyActor extends Actor with Stash {
  val actors = for {
    actorA <- ActorSelection(someRootActor / List("child1", "grandchild", "greatGrandchild")).resolveOne()
    actorB <- ActorSelection(someRootActor / List("child2")).resolveOne()
    actorC <- ActorSelection(someOtherRootActor / List("childC")).resolveOne()
  } yield ActorsLocated(actorA, actorB, actorC)
  actors recover {
    case t: Throwable =>
      ActorLocatingFailed(t)
  } pipeTo self

  val uninitialized: Receive = {
    case ActorsLocated(a, b, c) =>
      unstashAll()
      context.become(initialized(a, b, c))
    case ActorLocatingFailed(reason) =>
      throw new IllegalStateException(s"Failed to initialize: $reason")
    case _ =>
      stash()
  }

  def initalized(a: ActorRef, b: ActorRef, c: ActorRef): Receive = {
    // do your stuff here
  }

  def receive = uninitialized
}
```

Now you have a fully asynchronous startup for your Actor that grabs all of its dependencies properly.  On restart, you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense! How does `ActorsLocated` gets sent to self? Is it the yield that does it?

Comment: Wish there was some automatic akka functionality for acquiring the dependencies.

Comment: Could I also not just do: `for { ... } pipeTo self` and then just match on `Failure(t)` in my `recieve`? Seems like pipe passes on the failures.

Comment: It does, but I don't like it :)  I love that they take the time to propagate the failure, but `Failure(t)` lacks "context".  I strongly believe in establishing an application-level protocol for these sorts of things. Treating Futures as message transformers, in situations like this, works really well for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two possibilities:

"Injecting" the actors via message (e.g. ReadyToGo):

```
coPilotActor ! ReadyToGo(pilotActor)
pilotActor ! ReadyToGo(copilotActor)
```

Using ActorSelection:

```
 context.actorSelection(actorPath) ! Identify(<correlation_id>)
 // ...
 // response:
 case ActorIdentity(<correlation_id>, None) => // actor ref not found
 // or
 case ActorIdentity(<correlation_id>, Some(ref)) => // actor ref found
```

Because you are creating the two actors in plane, maybe you find a solution where you don't have to use actor selection in this case.

Comment: Hm.. I like your first suggestion, however what about the case when they need different number of dependencies? Actor selection route seems to require waiting at some point - and I have hard time synchronizing the various actors (for example how do I know when all of them are finished fetching their dependencies?)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to `pilotActor` and `copilotActor` directly as they are created inside the supervisor. :-( See line 57 in this file: https://github.com/danluu/akka-concurrency-wyatt/blob/master/src/main/scala/Plane.scala