# Will an assertion error be caught by in a catch block for java exception?

Tags: java, junit, try-catch, assert

Code:-

```
try {
    Assert.assertEquals("1", "2");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("I am in error block");
}
```

If the assert statements fails, I would like to capture the error in the catch block. I am trying with the above code and its not happening.

Will the assertion error be caught by in a catch block for java exception?

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyways? This seems like a gross misuse of `Assert` which is meant for Unit Testing

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You have almost answered your own question.  Your catch block will not catch the `AssertionError` that the `Assert` throws if it fails, because it is an `Error` (or, more specifically, it extends `java.lang.Error`).  [See the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) for more information on this.  Your catch block only catches `Throwable` objects that extend [`java.lang.Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)

If you really want to catch it - you need to use

```
catch (AssertionError e) {
...
```

***However***, as [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672077/838992) have [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29671936/838992), this is a very unusual way to use assertions - they should usually pass and if they fail it is very unusual for you to want to carry on the program execution.  That's why the failure throws an `Error` rather than an `Exception`.  You can read more about (not) catching `Error` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352780/when-to-catch-java-lang-error).

If you just want a test the variable value, it is preferred to use `if ( variableName == "1")`

**NB** if you are testing unit-test helper code, like a matcher, it might make sense to catch the `AssertionError`.

Comment: When one wants to see if a unit-test helper-class is doing the right thing (by unit-testing it ;-) ) one would expect to be able to catch such a AssertionError. That would be a valid situation to catch it, wouldn't it?

Comment: @gkephorus yes, I suppose it could be. Feel free to edit that in as an "N.B." if you like and I'll approve it :)

Comment: @JRichardSnape - I want to compare two java objects (obtained from json objects) which have only string variables with getters & setters i.e. POJO. I only want to compare some (not all) of the variables to determine a match. For one of the variables, only partial value should be compared. Is it a good idea to put all of my asserts into a try catch(AssertionError) block ? That way, I can return false in the catch part to indicate which field mismatched, with a useful error message string. This way, I won't have to write several if else. Sounds ok ?

Comment: With respect to: _"NB if you are testing unit-test helper code, like a matcher, it might make sense to catch the AssertionError"_ - I would recommend using `org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.handleAssertionErrors()`

Comment: `catch (AssertionError e) { }`  is not invoked in my case. Thou shall not catch `AssertionError` is the mantra here.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to catch both `Exception` and `Error` instances use:

```
...
catch (Throwable t)
{
...
}
```

Since both `Exception` and `Error` extend `Throwable`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I believe you are using JUnit for writing your tests. In that case, you should not catch your `Assert.assertEquals()` because they should pass for normal test execution. If it throws any exception, it means that your code is not performing as it should.

Comment: yes my assert code throws an exception. But i want to capture all errors such assertions or any other error by Exception class. How can i do it ?

Comment: You can't. `AssertionError` inherits from `Error` which means `try...catch` won't be able to handle them. See here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html. If you anyways need to catch them, see SpaceCowboy's answer.

Comment: @Aakash that's incorrect - this works fine: `try { throw new AssertionError(); } catch( AssertionError e){ System.out.println("ok");}`

Comment: @danyamachine as I said, we **should** not catch `AssertionError` or any `Error` for that matter. Errors are there to tell developer that something wrong has happened and program should not continue. It's a late reply, but better late than never :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to catch the errors in that way you need something like the following:

```
if (num == 1 || num == 2) {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

You could create your own exception class and pass in the message you want.